# Combine 2 flow with sequantially

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have two flows. The starting of a flow depends on successful completion of another flow. I can merge 2 flows with flatten merge, but it does not satisfy this condition.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*

val flow_1 = flowOf("loading_1", "loading_1", "success_1").onEach { delay(100) }
val flow_2 = flowOf("loading_2", "loading_2", "success_2").onEach { delay(200) }

fun main() = runBlocking<Unit>  {
   
    flowOf(flow_1, flow_2).flattenMerge().collect {
        println("Result $it")
    }
}
```

As soon as flow_1 emits the value of success_1, I want the flow_2 to start to emit.
If flow_1 emits error_1 value, I want flow_1 to retry 3 times.
If it fails 3 times, I want both flows to be closed.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `flattenConcat` instead of `flattenMerge` if you want to execute them sequentially. "Concat" is short for concatenate, e.g. to link in series.

Assuming that when flow 1 fails, it throws an Exception (rather than emitting a String as your description suggests), the Flow `retry` operator can handle the three tries.

You can tag the end of it with `catch` if you don't want failures to throw during the `collect` block.

Putting that together:

```
fun main() = runBlocking {  
    flowOf(
        flow_1.retry(3), 
        flow_2
    )
        .flattenConcat()
        .catch { println("Failed with $it") }
        .collect {
            println("Result $it")
        }
}
```

Supposing your Flow literally emits a failure state rather than throwing, you could use `onEach` to make it throw instead so `retry` will work:

```
fun main() = runBlocking {  
    flowOf(
        flow_1
            .onEach { if (it == "failure_1") throw IOException("Failed!") }
            .retry(3), 
        flow_2
    )
        .flattenConcat()
        .catch { println("Failed with $it") }
        .collect {
            println("Result $it")
        }
}
```